# Does MySql Have xml support like SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, xml

Does MySql Have xml support like SQL Server?
I have searched and can't seem to find anything.

In SQL-Server I can use `FOR XML` to build xml output from my queries.
Is a similar method available in MySQL 5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some extent, but not like MSSQL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html